# SharePoint 2010- I CANNOT USE WORKFLOWS, How to move documents to sub folders in a library automatically if the sub folder is selected in Category

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, library, drop-off-library

My Drop off folder workflows are not working because of windows path in sep 2018, and we didn't patch the server due to some red tape issues,

However i want to ease life of my users by creating a doc library and asking them to select the category(subfolder) where they want the document to be moved, and document moves there, i cant use workflows.

looking forward for expert helps.

Thanks,
learner.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Site Settings->Site Administration->Content and structure->Choose the documents, choose Action,Choose Move-> choose the sub folder to move the documents:

[image]

Comment: No luck with this as we need automation. :(